# Interactive jquery/php/mysql calculator - is this feasible?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

So I don't program regularly and it's been a while since I did anything. In any case I've been asked to explore this calculator web app and see if I can execute it. So far I've been exploring the jquery side of things with set values so I've been good. However, it's time to get a little bit more complicated and my experience with mysql and php is not great so I thought I'd ask if this is feasible before I delve full on into this.

Basically what I want to do is a calculator that can be a roughly divided in to two parts: base value and add-on modifiers.

Base value is formed by two components, a fixed value and a modifier. These would be in drop down menus and positioned fixed so the user can always change the base value. As an example drop down A might give a fixed value of £1,000,000 and drop down B might modify this by 1.4 resulting in base value of £1,400,000.

On top of the base value there are 3 ranges of add-on's with 9 different categories. So basically 9 times a radio switch with 3 options. Some of these might be modifiers such as "add 2%, 6% or 10%" to base value, some might be set values.

My question is: is it feasible to do this as an interactive app? As in would I need a form to be submitted each time to get to the final sum? I mean the algorithm isn't overly complicated but the number of different factors makes it a bit intimidating to me.

Can I submit each value to a table in mysql and retrieve new values interactively? The table is important to me as I want the user to be able to save the values so you can send a link to someone else and they can see what you've done.

I mean there are certain complexities such as if you change the set value of your base value which would result in first modifying this by the other factor and then adding on the number of complicated factors brought by the add-ons. You would effectively have to retrieve each value and run the whole algorithm each time something changed, correct?

If communicating with a table interactively is not feasible maybe I could execute the whole algorithm through javascript and have a separate "save" button which would then send each value to the table and give you a link?

I hope this made sense. Just to be clear I'm just asking for some guidance not for anyone to give me ready code. If this sounds like a feasible goal to reach I'll crack on it. You can then no doubt find me here in the near future with some more detailed questions haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is totally feasible for what you've described.

I would take your final approach and do all of the computations using Javascript (most likely attaching functions to onChange events) and have a Save button to insert the data.

You should create each new row using a randomly generated GUID as the unique primary key and have the resulting link send you to the same page with the GUID as a URL parameter. You can have a wrapper looking for the parameter and if it exists then load the data, otherwise give them an empty form.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you can start to work on the web app with a solid framework. I suggest you can use [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), which got stunning easy to understand documentation and examples help you start really quickly to start build the web app you want! I am using it now, and so far so good. However, you may need basic knowledge about web development:

> 1. PHP
> 2. JavaScript
> 3. JQuery
> 4. MySQL
> 5. HTML
> 6. CSS
> 7. Some graphic design knowledge like PS, Illustrator, etc

Hope that help you get started!
Btw, its a long journey of struggling, studying, frustration sometime :) But all that are very rewarding both internally for achievement and externally for the community benefit.

Enjoy! Hope you will be really successful.